# dynamically change bg color of a field in a form sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm new to sencha touch and I'm trying to dynamically change the bg color of a field.

I know there's a way to do it via sass and copmass, BUT if someone knows how to do it dynamically...

Thanks A lot,

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?  It's helpful to see what you've tried already.

Comment: Yes, I have tried:

    Ext.getCmp('').addCls('Red');

CSS:
    .Red{
    background-color:red !important;
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this

```
LinePanel.Toolbar.getComponent("finBtn").el.setStyle( { backgroundColor: '#4F4F4F' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Ext.getCmp('issue-estimated-hours').setStyle({backgroundColor: '#BA661B'});
```

where 'issue-estimated-hours' is the id that I assigned to the form field like this:

```
{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Estimated Hours',
                    id: 'issue-estimated-hours',
                    name: 'estimated_hours',
                    readOnly: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

**Ext.getCmp('yourcomponentId').setCls('red');**

In css
.red 
{ background-color:red}